# Reference about estimate of eigenfunction

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume $\varphi$ is the first eigenfunction of Laplacian with Dirchlet boundary condition  on a bounded convex smooth domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$. $\forall x\in \Omega$, 
$$
d(x,\partial\Omega)=\inf\limits_{y\in\partial\Omega} d(x,y)
$$
is the distance from $x$ to the boundary. If $\int_\Omega \varphi^2 =1$, whether there are some  estimate like
$$
g(d)\le \varphi(x) \le f(d)  ~?
$$

Comment: The first eigenfunction is defined up to a constant factor, so the claim cannot be true in the given form. It has to restated somehow.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I forget to write it.

Comment: The upper bound should follow from the Li-Yau gradient estimate (assuming you're fine with $f$ depending on $\lambda_1$). Not sure about the lower bound.